# How to view items in database selected by user in a django app?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a model `orders` that stores users orders at a restaurant. I want to create a view that allows me to show every item available in the database on the home page in a grid.

- Then when a user clicks on any of the items it should take them to a new page with more info on the item.
  How would I set logic for the view, to know what item the user clicked?

Comment: Did you try any code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not how we operate here. We expect you to tell and show us what you have tried, and then we help you with specific problems. We don't solve homework assignments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so i would recommend you to use Class-Based Views. Ones such as ListView and DetailView would fit your use case.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#making-friendly-template-contexts

A `views.py` with a Listview would look like this:

```
    from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
    from .models import Items
    
    class ItemsList(ListView):
        model = Items
        context_object_name = 'items_list'
        template_name = "menu/index.html" # Location of the template


    class ItemDetailList(DetailView):
        model = Items
        context_object_name = 'item'
        template_name = "menu/item.html" # Location of the template
```

`urls.py` In the same app folder, remember to include it in project urls.py

from django.urls import path

```
from .views import ItemsList, ItemDetailList
urlpatterns = [
  path("", ItemsList.as_view(), name="menu"),
  path("item/<int:pk>/", ItemDetailList.as_view(), name="item_detail"),
]
```

In a template you would reference the object by using the context_object_name which in the case of the list view would be `items_list`

In the path for the detail view with the `<int:pk>` you are passing the primary key of the object that you are referring to and then you reference it in your template which would show you the information about the item